# Message Passing Between Windows Webview and Native (Windows Universal)

Tags: javascript, windows, webview, win-universal-app

Is there an alternative approach to message passing between Windows Webview and native code besides the way the SDK describes via content URI's? Content URI"s are a great feature however, with my company's current deployment scheme this feature is not a viable solution for us. This is due to the major drawback of the feature requiring that all URI's which invoke native code be listed in the applications package manifest file. Unfortunately, we do not know at development time what the installed URL's will be. We have application settings for this which allow our users to dynamically set their URL. Any knowledge or direction  with this would be gratefully appreciated.